# Creating shortcut key in windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

My laptop "End" key is not working. Is it possible to create shortcut key for "End" key (i.e., CTRL + ALT + E).  I dont want to use 'create on screen keyboard'.

Thanks in advance
P.Padmanaban

Answer (score 1):

You can used KeyTweak to remap a other key on old "End" http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/KeyTweak.shtml